# Calculate remaining two corners of rectangle given two points and angle

Tags: trigonometry, angle, rectangles

I have a rectangle given two corners at opposite ends that we'll call A and B.
I need to be able to figure out the remaining corners given these two points and the angle by which the rectangle is rotated.

[image]

Excuse my sloppy drawing. I hope it gets the idea across.
The gray rectangle is rotated by an angle of alpha, which is roughly 20° in my sketch.

How would I be able to calculate the remaining corners?

Answer (score 0):

Some hints, I won't include a full solution, so you can try your self.

Let's call the upper left intersection of the black rectangle on the grey rectangle C
And D for the other side.
Given that the grey rectangle is actually a rectangle we know that each two facing sides are parallel, also it's easy to prove that AC and BD are parallel, Thus the shape ACBD is a parallelogram.

By definition each two facing angles of a parallelogram are the equal.

And finally we can use the fact that the sum of the angles of any triangle is equal to 180.

Comment: Thank you for your post.
Unfortunately I fail to see how the parallelogram would aid me in finding out the remaining corners, or how I would calculate points C and D to begin with.

I keep trying to think that sin and cos might help me, but I'm not sure whether that's the correct approach at all.

Comment: It would be better if you would begin solving it in any approach, and then share the problems you are facing so we can help you out.